# Al eliminar el registro de una tabla anidada, se borra de una lista, pero la tabla principal deja sus datos en ella

Tags: php, mysql

poseo una lista de datos donde se muestra el titulo de un proyecto (tabla proyecto) y de los alumnos (tabla alumnos) que están inscritos en el, estando estos guardados en una tabla anidada llamada Proyecto_Alumno.

tengo la opción de modificar y de eliminar los alumnos de el proyecto, pero ocurre que cuando le doy eliminar al registro para que borre de la lista de inscritos a los alumnos y el proyecto, queda igual el proyecto en la lista, los alumnos se eliminan pero el proyecto no.

OJO: quisiera borrar el proyecto de la lista, mas no de la base de datos

Captura del ERROR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aqui les dejo el formulario de listado de alumnos y proyectos

http://www.miblocdenotas.com/104116

aqui la funcion de eliminar

```
function bd_proyecto_alumno_eliminar($id)
{    
$sql=sql("DELETE FROM proyecto_alumno WHERE proy_id = '$id'");
}
```

Funcion para obtener datos:

```
function bd_proyecto_alumno_datos_todos(){
$sql = "SELECT 
          proy_id, proy_deno                
           FROM                
           proyecto
        ORDER BY proy_id ASC";
 $datos = sql2array( $sql );

 foreach ($datos as &$dato) { //faltaba el aspersan para que funcionara//
$dato['alumno']    = sql2array("SELECT 
                                    a.alum_id, b.cedu_alum,nom1_alum,nom2_alum, ape1_alum, ape2_alum
                                  FROM 
                                    proyecto_alumno a, alumno b 
                                  WHERE 
                                    a.proy_id='{$dato['proy_id']}' 
                                     AND a.alum_id=b.cedu_alum");
}
return $datos;
}
```

Comment: Esto se ve que el problema es cómo obtienes el listado de proyectos para mostrarlos, no con base de datos

Comment: actualizado con el codigo

Comment: pero es que tú mismo dices en la pregunta que no quieres que se borre el proyecto de la base de datos, y luego simplemente haces un `SELECT` de la tabla proyectos

Comment: eso para que muestre a proyecto pertenece esos integrantes, quisiera solo que mostrara pero una vez borrado el registro no quedara un proyecto vació en la lista. me explico?

Comment: Te explicas, pero yo te estoy diciendo el por qué. En todo caso, se ve que tiene una fácil solución, voy a postear en unos momentos

Comment: muchas gracias, por cierto, solo con darle a la flechita verde quiere decir que encontre la respuesta?

Comment: Sí, marcando la flechita verde (✓) eliges la respuesta como la aceptada, pero te recomiendo esperar un tiempo para que veas si recibes mejores respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la tabla `proyectos` tiene todos los proyectos que hay (o hubo), esto por diseño (explicas en tu pregunta que no quieres que se borre de la base de datos). En este caso, en vez de seleccionar todos los proyectos para ser mostrados, simplemente debes filtrar aquellos que no tienen alumnos:

```
SELECT p.proy_id, p.proy_deno                
FROM proyecto p
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM proyecto_alumno 
             WHERE proy_id = p.proy_id)
ORDER BY p.proy_id ASC
```

Comment: asi?

http://www.miblocdenotas.com/104131

claro sin el ss que se me fue

Comment: @VictorAlejandroAlvaradoVilo similar, pero te faltó darle el alias a la tabla `proyecto` (`FROM proyecto p`)

Comment: EXCELENTE MUCHAS GRACIAS, como le doy a la solucion?


el alias?

Comment: @VictorAlejandroAlvaradoVilo sí, la `p` después de `proyecto`. Es importante que esté

Comment: listo alli esta, por cierto tambien funcionaria eso con otra tabla igual pero en vez de alumnos tutores

Comment: function bd_proyecto_alumno_datos_todos(){$sql = "SELECT p.proy_id, p.proy_deno                
FROM proyecto p
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM proyecto_alumno 
             WHERE proy_id = p.proy_id)
ORDER BY p.proy_id ASC";

Comment: Si quieres obtener un listado de todos los proyectos que tengan al menos algún alumno, entonces sí

Comment: listo funciona para ambos MUCHISISMAS GRACIAS

Por cierto como le doy que encotntre la solucion?

Comment: @VictorAlejandroAlvaradoVilo Ya lo hiciste, la respuesta quedó marcada como aceptada. De todas formas, para el futuro, te recomiendo esperar un poco más de tiempo antes de aceptar. Siempre pueden llegar respuestas mejores

Comment: esta bien, fue porque funciono jejejeje